# Confide wrong confirmation number

Tags: php, laravel

I have project with confide. At first Thank for this package.
But something is wrong.

`\Confide::confirm($code)` always returns false. What's wrong? Please help

Comment: Not emough expereince with laravel or confide maybe on my side, but what is in `$code` ? For a start ...

Comment: do you have 'email_account_confirmation' set in your config file?

Answer (score 0):

Confide will check **confirmation_code** with **$code**

**$identity = ['confirmation_code' => $code]**

Make sure in your users table filed confirmation is not null and will be same as your $code